# TSQL updating from JSON array

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am stuck on updating/inserting rows from json array into SQL Server 2017.

I have the following structure:

```
{
    "ID":52,
    "Name":"Mark",
   "Surname":"Blake",
    "Age": 24
    "Cars":[
         {"ID":110,"Volvo":"2001-10-01","Color":"red"},
         {"ID":110,"Volvo":"2001-10-01","Color":"red"},
         {"ID":110,"Volvo":"2001-10-01","Color":"red"},
         {"ID":-1,"Volvo":"2001-10-01","Color":"red"},
         {"ID":-1,"Volvo":"2001-10-01","Color":"red"},
    ]
}
```

I am trying to do a merge basing on Cars array, when ID is -1 then insert to table, else update.

How to achieve this?

OK, I did it, but I've got an another problem.
I'd like to get also ID from higher level (I mean 52 in this case), it should looks like:

```
110 52 2001-10-01  red
110 52 2001-10-01  red
110 52 2001-10-01  red
-1  52 2001-10-01  red
-1  52 2001-10-01  red
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed you JSON, it was a bit incorrect.

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = '{
    "ID":52,
    "Name":"Mark",
   "Surname":"Blake",
    "Age": 24,
    "Cars":[
         {"ID":110,"Volvo":"2001-10-01","Color":"red"},
         {"ID":110,"Volvo":"2001-10-01","Color":"red"},
         {"ID":110,"Volvo":"2001-10-01","Color":"red"},
         {"ID":-1,"Volvo":"2001-10-01","Color":"red"},
         {"ID":-1,"Volvo":"2001-10-01","Color":"red"}
    ]
}'


SELECT  JSON_VALUE(t.[value], N'$.ID'),
        JSON_VALUE(t.[value], N'$.Volvo'),
        JSON_VALUE(t.[value], N'$.Color')
FROM OPENJSON(@json, N'$.Cars') as t
```

Output:

```
110 2001-10-01  red
110 2001-10-01  red
110 2001-10-01  red
-1  2001-10-01  red
-1  2001-10-01  red
```

Put that in CTE or temp table, then MERGE the primary table. Or you can at first INSERT (`WHERE ID = -1`) and UPDATE (`WHERE ID != -1`)

**Update:**

```
SELECT  f.[value],
        JSON_VALUE(c.[value], N'$.ID'),
        JSON_VALUE(c.[value], N'$.Volvo'),
        JSON_VALUE(c.[value], N'$.Color')
FROM OPENJSON(@json) f
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(@json,N'$.Cars') c
WHERE f.[key] IN ('ID')
```

Output:

```
52  110 2001-10-01  red
52  110 2001-10-01  red
52  110 2001-10-01  red
52  -1  2001-10-01  red
52  -1  2001-10-01  red
```

Comment: I did it the same just few minutes ago, but I've got a another problem.
I'd like to get also ID from higher level (I mean 52 in this case), it should looks like:

110 52 2001-10-01  red
110 52 2001-10-01  red
110 52 2001-10-01  red
-1  52 2001-10-01  red
-1  52 2001-10-01  red

Comment: Do you have an idea how to achieve this? I've edited my post. Thanks for help!

Comment: If you JSON will not have more than 1 datapart you can simply add `JSON_VALUE(@json,N'$.ID')`